# Google Chrome crashes on loading sites in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I haven't made any changes to Chrome or any other file but whenever I load a website on Google Chrome I get this message:

```
[11180:11180:0517/040053.065219:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(368)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[11180:11180:0517/040054.206791:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
--2019-05-17 04:00:58--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.27.206, 2404:6800:4009:800::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.27.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’
```

On Firefox its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a coredump file? It might be a good idea to check what is going on with your Chrome.

Make sure that coredump support enabled in your system:

```
unlimit -c unlimited
```

Additionally, run the following command to see where your coredump files are stored:

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern
```

Install gdb (debugger) if you don't have one:

```
apt install gdb
```

Now run the debugger:

```
gdb path/to/the/chrome path/to/the/coredump
```

Check this out for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis

Use bc (backtrace) command to see what exactly is happening before the program crashes with a core file.

Comment: Hi, thanks i checked it out and the error was i that there was a conflict in my user and root user directory.
When i deleted and reinstalled chrome settings were not getting deleted from root directory.
It was solved when i manually deleted all of them.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sounds like it was resolved in a much simpler way :-) Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: @VinayakShrivastava Post that as an answer. It worked for me as well.